# Login page rendering inside the index page after session time out

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security

i'm trying to build a angularjs application with using spring security for authorization. the application has the expected behavior up to now. The issue i'm getting is that when the session time outs and the user tries to click on a link the login page is getting loaded inside the index.html where i render all my content using a ng-view.

how can i render the login page correct when the user session time outs.

here's my  spring security configuration.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/signout")
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/signout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/app.css", "/resetpassword/**","/api/user/resetpassword/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/testApp/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
             //Enforce HTTPS
            .and().requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
            .and()
            .rememberMe().key("testApp");
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Imagining your code seems very difficult. Please include some code so people here can help you.

Comment: i'm not sure what code to add. but i'll update my question with the spring security configurations.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. I can explain what is happening on the Angular side...

Angular asks server for a partial, server says you are not logged in (302)... here is the login page... Angular displays that while thinking it's the partial is requested..

Only thing I can think of is trying to figure out how to read the header response 302 on the partial request and intercept before login page is loaded instead of partial.

Comment: i found this link http://blog.akquinet.de/2014/09/05/angularjs-in-wars-the-case-of-the-session-timeout/ it proposes a method. but i didnt get time to try it out. let me know if it helps.